# Expressions pour attirer l'attention des enfants inconnus

Tags: politesse, enfants

Je vous propose la situation suivante :

> Vous êtes dans le bus. Un(e)<sup>1</sup> enfant s'assoit à côté de vous, vous empêchant de sortir sans lui parler. Vous ne le/la connaissez pas et, comme ses parents sont aussi là, vous ne voulez pas faire d'impair et dire quelque chose de maladroit.
>
> Votre arrêt est proche et vous voulez l'informer, mais il/elle ne fait pas d'attention à vous (ce n'est qu'un enfant, après tout).
>
> Que dites-vous pour attirer son attention, puisque vous ne connaissez pas son nom ?

---

C'est une vraie situation qui m'est arrivée ce matin, et de plus, il m'arrive souvent de chercher de quelle façon m'adresser à un enfant dont je ne connais pas le nom.

Voici des propositions  auxquelles j'ai déjà pensé :

1. *Les enfants* — au pluriel, mais je ne sais pas quoi dire s'il n'y en a qu'un ?
2. *Gamin/Gamine* — je ne sais pas pourquoi, mais pour moi cet expression peut être un peu péjorative ?
3. *Mon petit/ma petite* — j'ai des difficultés ici, j'ai compris que cela pourrait avoir un connotation sexuelle qu'il vaut mieux éviter
4. *???/Demoiselle* — Franchement je n'ai aucune idée de comment l'utiliser.

---

<sup>1. Vous notez que j'ai mis les deux genres, c'est parce que je voulais également savoir quelles différences existent quand on parle à une jeune fille ou un jeune garçon.</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Les enfants* est idiomatique, mais ne s'accommode effectivement pas du singulier.

J'ai l'impression que *gamin* est plus acceptable en Belgique, mais c'est peut-être dû au film "C'est arrivé près de chez vous"...

Voici deux propositions passe-partout :

- *Jeune homme*
- *Mademoiselle*<sup>1</sup>

et deux autres plus familières et un peu humoristiques :

- *Mon petit bonhomme*
- *Jeune fille*

En dehors de *mon petit bonhomme*, ces apostrophes entraînent normalement le vouvoiement.

Sinon, le tutoiement s'impose pour un jeune enfant<sup>2</sup> et on peut donc s'adresser directement à lui comme ceci:

- *S'il te plait, est-ce que tu pourrais me laisser passer ?*

<sup>1</sup> <sub>*Demoiselle* ne s'emploie pas pour apostropher quelqu'un. Aujourd'hui on ne rencontre guère ce mot ailleurs que dans quelques expressions comme *demoiselles d'honneur*.</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>Un enfant désigne autant un garçon qu'une fille, il n'est pas nécessaire de préciser un(e) enfant.</sub>

Comment: J’accepte celle-ci parce qu’elle offre des suggestions/alternatifs, mais toutes les réponses m’aident.

Answer (score 3):

Dans cette situation, je m'adresserais à eux simplement en leur disant *Excusez-moi*/*S'il vous plaît*.

Mais des quatre propositions, seule la première, *les enfants*, me semble naturelle (surtout pas *gamin* qui est péjoratif). Je ne vois pas d'équivalent au singulier cependant.

Comment: Merci de répondre. J’attendrai d’autre suggestions avant d’accepter, mais c’est au moins util

Answer (score 2):

Dans cette situation, si tu es assis côté fenêtre, celui qui est assis côté couloir sait que tu vas devoir descendre du bus à un moment où à un autre. Donc, quand tu lui dis "excusez-moi" ou "pardon" cela sous-entend que tu vas le déranger pour descendre du bus. Ça marche dans toutes les langues.

Si l'enfant est occupé, par exemple en train de jouer ou de lire, et qu'il t'ignore, le plus simple est de dire aux parents que tu vas descendre du bus. Ils ont déjà pris le bus, donc ils ont l'habitude.

> Les enfants — au pluriel, mais je ne sais pas quoi dire s'il n'y en a qu'un ?

Non, ça ne marche qu'au pluriel, et pas dans cette situation. Ça ressemble à l'anglais "guys!" qui s'utilise entre gens qui se connaissent au moins un peu, c'est un peu familier, plutôt à utiliser quand tu les connais, par exemple quand les enfants sont chez toi en train de jouer dans le jardin et tu veux les appeler.

> Gamin/Gamine — je ne sais pas pourquoi, mais pour moi cet expression peut être un peu péjorative ?

Oui, péjoratif ou au moins familier en français de France, je sais pas pour les autres pays. En anglais, ça s'approche de "brat".

> Mon petit/ma petite

Ça fait pédophile. À éviter.

> Monsieur/Mademoiselle

Si tu disais ça à un enfant de 8 ans, ce serait amusant. C'est pas malpoli, en fait tu peux même en faire une blague, mais si tu es anglophone tu peux noter que ça correspond à peu près à appeler l'enfant "Sir" ou "Madam".

Comment: Dire *monsieur* à un petit garçon ou *madame* à une petite fille est décalé et peut être un trait d'humour mais dire *mademoiselle* à une petite fille de huit ans n'est ni "amusant" ni "une blague". C'est au contraire la norme et même l'une des rares occasions acceptables d'utiliser *mademoiselle* aujourd'hui.